# Check version of vuetify

Tags: npm, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I have not found anything about that. Regarding the very quick modifications from version to version: How to check which version of vuetify is installed?

Answer (score 23):

To check which version of `vuetify` is installed use npm's [`ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) command.

For example:

- **To check which version is installed globally:**

  Run the following command:

  ```
  npm ls -g --depth 0 vuetify
  ```
- **To check which version is installed locally within your project:**

  Firstly, `cd` to the project directory and then run:

  ```
  npm ls --depth 0 vuetify
  ```

**Notes:**

You can also omit the `--depth 0` part to get the versions of all instances, i.e. show all versions of `vuetify` including those which may be a dependency of another package.

You'll see something like the following logged to your console. The part after the `@` symbol indicates the version number:

> `└── vuetify@1.2.6`

If `vuetify` is not installed you'll see the following:

> `└── (empty)`